# how can i use a particular UIActionSheet's button with some actioning (explain in brief) in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how can i use a particular UIActionSheet's button with some actioning (explain in brief) in iphone ?

Comment: okie we are going to explain you,,, are you going to pay us ;). Please ask specific questions, this is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/09/how-to-use-uiactionsheet/

http://iphoneinaction.manning.com/iphone_in_action/2009/06/uiactionsheet-part-one-alternate-user-input.html

Go through these links. You will get some idea :)